# Unable to run my django server connectinng changing database engine to msql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to connnect MySQL to my django app. I keep on receive an error message suggesting me to install my SQL client first. When I run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Here is the errro message I receive:

```
> (guessgame) Maiks-MBP:guessgame maiknoungoua$ python manage.py runserver
> Watching for file changes with StatReloader
> Exception in thread django-main-thread:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/maiknoungoua/.local/share/virtualenvs/guessgame-o_cdbTdf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
> import MySQLdb as Database
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
>
```

Can anyone help ?
Thanks in advance for the help.

I tried sourcing my export path in the bash profile

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH=$HOME/omnetpp-5.6.2/bin:$HOME/omnetpp-5.2.1/tools/macosx/bin:$PATH
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=$HOME/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/plugins

alias ll='ls -lGaf'

export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

For connection to the DBMS, Django ORM uses already existing modules (like `psycopg2` for PostgreSQL or `mysqlclient` for MySQL in your case). So, whenever you are trying to connect to any kind of database, that Django supports, you also need to have corresponding module installed in your environment.

To solve this problem, you need to install `mysqlclient`.

For pip:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

For poetry:

```
poetry add mysqlclient
```

For more information, you can look over official [Github page](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/blob/main/README.md)

P.S. If you are using python2, you need to use `MySQL-python` instead of `mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer it help a lot towards the resolution. When I ran that commannnd the output suggest some missing package that I was able to install.
This issue can be considered resolved. I was able to install mysqlclient and to run my django server.